# While performing google search using selenuim why x-path is not preffered?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
public void googlesearch() throws InterruptedException
{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(1000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[3]")).sendKeys("Ankush");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]")).click();
```

using above code i am trying to search. But it is throwing error that element is disabled.

Comment: how about posting the error too?

Comment: what error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to search on `Google` using `xpath`. Actually you are locating wrong element to search on `Google`, It just pretty simple without using `xpath` as below:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Ankush");
element.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Assignment2 {
public static void main(String args[])
{

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("yahoo");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();    
}
}
```

Try this It's Working for me